# Javascript callback function error

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm trying to become more familiar with callback functions in Javascript. I've created a simple app to push a new member to a development team array. I'm trying to use the addDev function as my callback practice. I'm receiving an error: `Uncaught TypeError: addDev is not a function`.

```
var devTeam = [];

function devMember(fName, lName, addDev){
    this.firstName = fName;
    this.lastName = lName;
    this.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
    addDev(fullName);
}

function addDev(member){
    devTeam.push(member);
    console.log(devTeam);
}

devMember('Jay', 'Spears');
```

Comment: You're not passing the callback function; you're just passing the names.  Your `devMember()` function takes 3 arguments.

Comment: devMember should have 3 parameters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you never passed `addDev` to `devMember`.

Try 
    devMember('Jay', 'Spears', addDev);

Even though `addDev` is defined (hoisted), because you're calling the third argument to `devMember` also `addDev`, you're overriding it. And then you don't pass anything as a third argument when you invoke `devMember('Jay', 'Spears')`, so it is undefined in the execution context of `devMember`.

Comment: `addDev` is global function, shouldn't it be called?

Comment: @Tushar No, because the `addDev` declaration in the function arguments shadows the global declaration, and the variable will be undefined if no third parameter is passed. The code would have worked without this third parameter.

Comment: @JoshSpears yep, if you remove that third parameter from `devMember`, or even call it something else (either way, not recommended), it would work.  The best thing is to call it something other than `addDev`, and then pass `addDev` as an argument when you invoke `devMember`.

Comment: @caasjj I renamed addDev to a proper name. `function devMember(fName, lName, pushMember){};`

Comment: That'll do it, as long as you remember to pass in `addDev` when you invoke `devMember`.

Comment: @caasjj `devMember('Jay', 'Spears', addDev);` FTW.